# How do I drag the formula to lookup all the values needed?

Tags: excel, vba, xlookup

In this module the goal is to open a different workbook and set up an xlookup.
I managed to do this in one cell but I can't figure out how to 'drag' that 'formula' down like you would in Excel.

Just to point out: I need to set up this xlookup in column Y with as many rows as are in column C.
What can be done to put my first xlookup in Y9 and then another in Y10,Y11,Y12... ?

My 'searchedValue' will change with each line - so, the xlookup in Y10 will be looking for value in C10 (not in C9).

```vb
Sub ImportBaselineData()

    Dim FileLocation As String

    FileLocation = Application.GetOpenFilename

    If FileLocation = "False" Then
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim searchedValue As Range
    Dim searchedColumn As Range
    Dim returnedValue As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ImportWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileLocation)
    Set searchedValue = Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Range("C9"))
    Set searchedColumn = ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("H9", Range("H9").End(xlDown))
    Set returnedValue = ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("H9", Range("H9").End(xlDown))

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overall Analysis").Range("Y9") = Application.XLookup(searchedValue, searchedColumn, returnedValue)
    ImportWorkbook.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try recording a macro to see how its done?

Answer (score 1):

I used slightly different approach. The below works just fine:

```
    Sub ImportBaselineDara()

    Dim FileLocation As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet

   

    FileLocation = Application.GetOpenFilename

    If FileLocation = "False" Then

        Beep

        Exit Sub

    End If

   

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ImportWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileLocation)

   

    ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B8", Range("B8").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Baseline data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

       

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overall Analysis")

''mpc

    With ws.Range("Y9:Y" & ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

        .Formula = "=XLOOKUP(C9,'Baseline data'!G:G,'Baseline data'!G:G,""not in baseline"")"

        .Value = .Value

        End With

 

  ImportWorkbook.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```